# Change values of predefined Items in Multichoice AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-alertdialog

I have been trying to implement a multichoice alertdialog and for the most part everything is clear and understandable but the alertdialog gets the state of the items from a boolean array and all the items are set as true. I can't quite work out how I could change the state of an item in the array if it is checked in the alertdialog.

```
 private void showCategorySelectionDialog() {
        // Prepare the dialog by setting up a Builder.
        final String selectionTitle = "Show on map: ";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(selectionTitle);

        final String[] categories = new String[]{"Camping grounds","Abandoned places","Nature areas","Lookout Points"};
        
        // Find the current map type to pre-check the item representing the current state.
        boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[]{
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true
        };

        // Add an OnClickListener to the dialog, so that the selection will be handled.
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(

                categories,
                checkedItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                      //check which item is clicked and if it was true then set it as false.
                        if (isChecked && checkedItems[which] == true){
                            checkedItems[which]= false;
                        }else{
                      //If item was clicked and the value was false then set it as true.
                            checkedItems[which] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // Build the dialog and show it.
        AlertDialog categoryDialog = builder.create();
        categoryDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        categoryDialog.show();
    }
```

This current solution does not change values and my assumptions are that I am handling the Array in an incorrect way but I am not sure how the right way would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the value for an element in the array when it was checked then you can try to set the value to be equal with the `isChecked` variable that is passed through `onClick()` method.

Check the code below:

```
        // Add an OnClickListener to the dialog, so that the selection will be handled.
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(
                categories,
                checkedItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        checkedItems[which] = isChecked;
                    }
                }
        );
```